# Calling a Model inside another Model - Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models listed. I want to be able to call the first model, into the second and have its fields show up as if they were originally in the first. And once I can do that, I want those fields to only show up if a certain condition was met.

Essentially Id like to be able to have conditional fields in an object that appear when triggered. In this case when the "Application_Status" == 'Unavailable'

Applications should only have the fields under 'Incident' if their status is 'Unavailable'. Otherwise they don't need any of that information and it does not exist.

This is where I'm starting from. At this point it only gives me a blank drop down for incident.

```
from django.db import models

class Incident(models.Model):
    Incident_Number = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        default='',
    )
    Incident_Link = models.URLField(
        default=''
    )
    Point_of_Failure = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        default=''
    )
    Description_of_Issue = models.TextField(
        max_length=500,
        default=''
    )

class Application(models.Model):
    Application_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    AVAILABLE = 'av'
    UNAVAILABLE = 'un'
    Application_Status_Choices = (
        (AVAILABLE, ' Available'),
        (UNAVAILABLE, 'Unavailable'),
    )

    Application_Status = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=Application_Status_Choices,
        default=AVAILABLE,

    )


    incident = models.OneToOneField(
        Incident,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
        default=''
    )
```

Comment: Nothing here would give you any kind of drop down, blank or not. You need to give more information about how you are generating that, and how you are relating these models together.

Comment: Have you considered making a base Application model and a child ApplicationWithIncident model?

Comment: The incident onetoonefield shows up as a empty drop down list in the admin page.

The applications themselves and their basic info need to be retained regardless of their status. and then, when it is marked unavailable, I need to have extra fields with the information specific to the incident  appear.

Comment: Once it becomes available, again, the basic information should remain, and the incident information should no longer exist in the object.
I could have one single model with all the fields in there, and just leave it blank when its available. but I feel like that isnt as clean, and leaves the door open to residual data in objects that is no longer true. *ie, the incident data would have to be cleaned out upon the status becoming available. I could show/hide those fields in the view depending on the status. 

I was just hoping for a more logic based solution than a smoke and mirrors one.

Comment: I realize its been awhile, but I wanted to add what I ended up doing. I built in logic that resets the incident data to their defaults upon the application becoming available. I then have 2 different HTML templates that are served based on the applications status, one with incident data, one without.

Comment: What I was initially looking for is similar to a Join in SQL. But it turns out that creating an incident object is more overhead than just punching in a ticket number into the Application object, and using an API call to update the ticket data from Service Now. If the site gets too much traffic, then we may have a problem with API call frequency, but engineering some sort of API cache shouldnt be too hard when the time comes. Bonus is we dont have to update ticket information in multiple places.